# I feel lost in learning cocos2d-iphone through Programming Guide and Source code

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

As title.
I have learning cocos2d through Programming Guide in http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:index#beginners_guide.
Besides,I read the source code of cocos2d-iphone.
But I don't feel I learn much.**Because all the “real codes” are encapsulated in opengl es or apple libraries.**
I can not know how to implement some effects by myself.Also I do not know how to improve.
Needing some suggestions.What is the next？

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your question will be closed for not being a "real question" (or too vague), but instead of starting with Cocos2D... perhaps you could consider learning the fundamentals of iOS coding (which is Objective C) from the beginning?

Myself, I'd recommend "Objective C Programming" by Aaron Hillegass & Mark Fenoglio.  Here's where you can pick up an e-book copy:  http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/objective-c-programming/id470896293?mt=11

Comment: Thanks.I think I should do more coding using Objective C.Maybe the real reason is that I am not familiar with Objective C.Coding,coding,coding..